# flash as3 best to use xml, a class object or static array to load information?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I'm currently writing a feature for an interactive periodic table which dynamically displays the name of the element and other properties when you hover over the element. I have thought of three ways to do this and I am wondering which is the best, memory-wise and speed-wise, for loading this information.

1. make a class with an array ( new Array("hydrogen", "helium", "lithium",...etc.)), instantiating it, then accessing the info with object.arr[i]
2. make a class with a static array (otherwise, same as no.1), importing it, then accessing the info with class.arr[i]
3. put the information into an external xml file and accessing it from there.

The 3rd method seems excessive as you have to go through the hassle of adding event listeners for URLloader every time.
Is there any difference between the 1st and 2nd way? (What is happening in terms of memory when you are importing a class - is the entire array added to memory?)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try using xml (might as well learn something new!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the third method :)
Getting used to use xml for storing content is always good, and it's only some lines of code:

```
 var myXML:XML;
 var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
 myLoader.load(new URLRequest("yourXmlData.xml"));


 function processXML(e:Event):void {
      myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
 }
```

In this case you could go for the hardcoded solution too, but I really prefer to have the content and the code separated. It's easier to mantain everything if in the future you decide to add extra content to every cell (and as @weltraumpirat says, you don't need to recompile everything when info changes)

Answer (score 2):

If all you are storing are strings, you can use a Vector, something like:

```
var tableData:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
tableData.push("Hydrogen","Helium","...");
```

Vectors are faster than arrays. Depending on how you are implementing you can also use a Dictionay.

If you are storing more than 1 value for each element you can use a multidimensional Vector as well.

Using an external xml file is slower.

Comment: +1 for Vectors. The xml file method doesn't have to be much slower, though - you can serialize the loaded XML into a Vector and use that for processing.  Externalizing data is generally not a bad idea, because it is simply more maintainable that way - no need to recompile your application if you have to correct a typo...

Comment: @Weltraumpirat, I agree, xml is very nice for maintainability as has been proven time and time again :) and the extra time it takes to load it really isn't bad at all.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way is to have a reference to a XMLDocument and work only with nodes of that document. That way you don't have to duplicate/parse a new xml, the node refers to a node on your main XML so there is no data duplication. I'm saying this in case you are going to create a custom class that extends movie clip, and instantiate it for all of your objects. Something like

```
package com.package.your{ 
public class YourClass extends MovieClip {
private var _node:XMLNode;
public function YourClass() {
public function setData(__xmlNode:XMLNode):void{
_node = __node
//do what you want with the info like on rollover, display this one info from the node or whatever, your clips holds all of the info that it might display...

...
```

Then i guess you will create your table using a loop so then you go

```
for(var i:uint ...
myInstance = new YourClass();
this.addChild(myInstance);
myInstance.setData(__xmlDoc.firstChild.childNodes[i]);
```

And have the XMLDocument in the Main or a static class if you want. You could also use XMLList instead of XMLDocument / Node, i'm just used to the "old" XML way...